# How to see sfdx commands processing indicator in VSCode

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code

Is it possible to see some processing/loading indicator when I do sfdx commands in vscode terminal?

Comment: When you use any sfdx command with command pallete it does shows a progress indicator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like with any terminal command, I do not believe there is a way to see a loading indicator. Some commands like `sfdx force:package:install` or `sfdx force:mdapi:deploy` will provide continuous status feedback in terminal:

[image]

The [Salesforce CLI Integration](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-core) for VS Code provides a status notification and additional details in the Output panel when clicking on buttons like the **org open** button:

[image]

Additionally, any command made using the [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) will show in the Output panel and provide a status notification:

[image]